# Blender Python API add property to object

Tags: python, class, object, blender

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
reference_object= bpy.context.active_object
reference_object.add_variable(name='some_property',value=5)
reference_object.some_property
```

and it would print back 5

I basically am trying to add a property to an object that's already been created and does not have the particular variable I'm trying to add in it's class. I tried looking up how to do this but I cannot seem to understand some of the other posts. Any advice would be great.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do:

```
reference_object['some_property'] = 5
```

And then access it:

```
reference_object['some_property']
# Prints back 5
```